# Using Swype, or a Swype-like keyboard, is there a way to type without lifting my finger up?

Tags: swype

Swype is great, but I feel like it could be even faster/more fluid if you just dragged your finger over the space bar/performed some other gesture to insert a space between words, rather than having to pick up your finger. Is there any way to add functionality like this to Swype? Alternatively, are there any good gesture-based keyboards that support this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's recent, but [SwiftKey Flow](http://www.swiftkey.net/flow/) does exactly this. It's currently in beta, but seems stable and robust. It's also an excellent alternative tap keyboard if the Swype style isn't for you.

Answer (score 1):

Your lifting the finger between words IS a gesture. And I guess that's the fastest & easiest one without confusing the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

I think there will probably no such thing.

The reason is that it would be to hard for the keyboard to know when you are swiping over the space bar and when not. I know it sounds simple for you, but a lot of users will swipe over the space bar even though they want the buttons on the lower row. So there will need to be some recognition over when it should be the spacebar and when not. Which is not that simple.

And as an extra point, the lifting of your finger means the end of your word. This is rather useful information that can be used for the algorithm to determine the length of the word, and the words that would fit best. And when you know the length, you have very useful information to determine the word you were probably swiping.

I guess it will take a rather intelligent keyboard for this to work. And by intelligent, I mean a keyboard that will have to do a lot of calculations for the prediction of the word (because swiping is actually predicting words). And if you need a lot of calculations when you are typing, you will be draining the battery of your phone rather rapidly. And I don't think you want your battery to be drained because you were typing something.

Answer (score -1):

try this Jellybean new keyboard .
It is fast enough.

http://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=1966456

Comment: You still have to lift your fingers up.